# getting same top 1 result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    IT_approvaldate 
FROM  
    t_item  
WHERE 
    IT_certID_fk_ind = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 IT_certID_fk_ind 
                        FROM t_item  
                        WHERE IT_rfileID_fk = '4876') 
ORDER BY 
    IT_typesort
```

Result when running this query:

[image]

I need get top 1 result. (2013-04-27 00:00:00) problem is when I select top 1, getting 2nd result.

[image]

I believe reason for that order by column value same in those two result.
please see below,

[image]

However I need get only `IT_approvaldate` column top 1 as result of my query.

How can I do this? Can anyone help me to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You got what you asked for. Both values are "top", when sorted by the column that they have the same value for. What additional criteria do you want to sort by? Do you just want to exclude NULL? Or do you want the most recent approval date? Or the least recent?

Comment: only one criteria is `IT_typesort` @Blorgbeard

Comment: Clearly it isn't, because you said `null` is not acceptable in the example. Why should it be the other value and not null?

Comment: null acceptable but as this example 2013-04-27 is top 1. but when i select top 1, null result (2nd result) getting to top 1.

Comment: No it's not "top 1", the order is not defined. It's returned in arbitrary order. A table does not have an inherent order - you have to completely define the order you want with the `order by` clause.

Comment: plus, so you know, `TOP` is not actually determined until AFTER the `ORDER BY`. In fact, logically, it is the last action performed in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use below query and check

```
SELECT IT_approvaldate FROM  t_item  WHERE IT_certID_fk_ind =(SELECT DISTINCT top 1 IT_certID_fk_ind FROM  t_item  WHERE IT_rfileID_fk ='4876' ) and IT_approvaldate is not null ORDER BY IT_typesort
```

This will remove null values from the result

Comment: no i need null value too. i cannot ignore null values. my result can be null value. problem is i want to get top result as 01 query

Comment: Include IT_approvaldate in order by and check what results you get.  check both the cases order by asc & desc.

Comment: asc & desc gettign same result

Answer (score 1):

`TSQL` Select queries are not inherently deterministic. You must add a tie-breaker or by another row that is not.

The theory is `SQL Server` will not presume that the `NULL` value is greater or lesser than your row, and because your select statement is not logically implemented until after your `HAVING` clause, the order depends on how the database is setup.

Understand that SQL Server may not necessarily choose the same path twice unless it thinks it is absolutely better. This is the reason for the `ORDER BY` clause, which will treat NULLs consistently (assuming there is a unique grouping).

**UPDATE:**
It seemed a good idea to add a link to MSDN's documentation on the `ORDER BY`.  Truly, it is good practice to start from the `Standard`/`MSDN`. [ORDER BY Clause - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Comment: Actually, SQL Server recognizes NULLs in ORDER BY, it's always treated as less than the lowest value.

Comment: @dean however, that is the ORDER BY clause. there is no guarantee that the rest of your query will consistently run the same way without it.

Comment: Agreed, ORDER BY is absolutely necessary for a predictable order. My remark was about the "SQL Server will not presume that the NULL value is greater or lesser than your row" - ORDER BY semantics is clear wrt NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want NULL to be the last value in the sorted list you can use `ISNULL` in `ORDER BY` clause to replace `NULL` by `MAX value of DATETIME` 
Below code might help:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 IT_approvaldate
FROM  t_item 
WHERE IT_certID_fk_ind = (SELECT DISTINCT top 1 IT_certID_fk_ind FROM  t_item  WHERE IT_rfileID_fk ='4876' ) 
ORDER BY IT_typesort ASC, ISNULL(IT_approvaldate,'12-31-9999 23:59:59') ASC;
```

Comment: `SELECT  TOP 1 IT_approvaldate
FROM  t_item 
WHERE IT_certID_fk_ind = (SELECT DISTINCT top 1 IT_certID_fk_ind FROM  t_item  WHERE IT_rfileID_fk ='4876' ) 
ORDER BY IT_typesort ASC, ISNULL(IT_approvaldate,GETDATE()) ASC;` working well need to test. thank you. little bit changed `GETDATE()`

Comment: @Ashan Can you please mark this as answer if it is working?